# List all post titles from all custom post types with group, exclude some

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, custom-post-type

I am able to display a list of all post titles in every custom post type like this...

```
$args = array(
'post_type'         => 'any',
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'exclude'           => ''
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
echo '<ul>';
while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php echo "\n";
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
echo '</ul>';
```

...which displays all post titles in a big flat list.

But I also want to be able to do a couple of things:

1) Have them grouped with the custom post type name above each group in a `<h2>`, so the output might look like this for example:

```
<h2>Testimonials</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Some guy</li>
    <li>Some other person</li>
</ul>
<h2>Restaurants</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Chinese</li>
    <li>Indian</li>
    <li>Japanese</li>
</ul>
```

2) Allow specific post types to be excluded. I'm guessing something like `'exclude' => array('clothes', 'people'),` might be all that's needed, but I'm unsure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for starters, you can order the posts by post type : `'type' - Order by post type (available since Version 4.0). ('post_type' is also accepted.)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below working code for you.

```
  $posttypes= array_values(get_post_types()); // get all post types
  $exclude_post_type=array('post'); // exclude the post types which you don't want to include
  $final_posttypes = array_diff($posttypes, $exclude_post_type); // this is final array which will use in post_type.

        $args = array(
        'post_type'         => $final_posttypes ,
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'exclude'           => '',
        'orderby'=>'post_type',
        'order'=>'asc'
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

        echo '<ul>';
        $last_post_type='';
            while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); 
                $currpost_type =$post->post_type;
                if($currpost_type!=$last_post_type) echo "<li>{$post->post_type}</li>";
                ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <?php echo "\n";
                $last_post_type = $currpost_type;
            endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
        echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: there are a few errors in that code which I cleaned up while testing, but it didn't work and I realised it's missing a vital part (the custom post type heading) anyway.

Comment: if($currpost_type!=$last_post_type) echo "<li>{$post->post_type}</li>"; this is used to display custom post type and code is tested so It must be working.

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but that's not quite right. Your code shows the post type being displayed next to each post. In my original question, I demonstrated how it should be - with a heading above a group of each post type.

Comment: Its just extra info which I had displayed beside the post title, looks like you haven't run this code check the screen-shot http://prntscr.com/jwkf62 post_type is displayed only once.

Comment: awesome - that seems to work. Regarding the second part of my question, how can I exclude particular post types? I thought `'exclude' => array('clothes', 'people')` might work, but it doesn't. Any suggestions?

Comment: In 'post_type'         => 'any', write down only those post types which you want.

Comment: Thanks, but that is different to what I require. I need to be able to exclude specific post types. The reason is because our client will occasionally add more post types (using an interface in the WP backp-end), and so I don't want to have to keep checking to see if he has added any new post types and then go and add them to the script every time. It would be a maintenance headache. But there are a few specific post types that we will never want to show, hence it would be easier if the query gets 'any' post type and we simply exclude the post types we never want to show.

Comment: Ok got your point but there is no exclude in wp_query you can achieve using another way let me edit my answer it will work for you.